# I can't access in wp correct folder directory

Tags: wordpress

Folder Directory-
http://edeshprotikhon.test/wp-content/themes/edeshprotikhon/map/

I am trying this code for iframe src, but not working...

" style="height: -webkit-fill-available; width: 100%;" frameborder="0">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When referencing files inside the themes folder, you want to use a function for outputting the correct path in relation to where the file you are working on resides. A function like `<? get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>` or `<? get_template_directory_uri(); ?>` should give the correct path. so for your iframe, you would want something like this:

```
<iframe src="<? get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/map" style="height: -webkit-fill- 
available; width: 100%;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Also make sure the map file/folder has the same permissions that the rest of the theme folder has.